# How to get input with windows api

Tags: c++, winapi

Some friends and I are starting to make a video game. I'm pretty new to the windows api though and to do some prototyping for our early stages I need to know how to parse input given via the windows message system. The main thing I need to do is get input from the keyboard in the form of what key is pressed. Any idea on how to parse lParam and wParam in the winProc function to find what key was pressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [WM_KEYDOWN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `wParam
The virtual-key code of the nonsystem key.`

From [WM_CHAR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646276%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `wParam
The character code of the key.`

The latter is pretty straightforward, whereas the former can be referenced here: [Virtual Key Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Let's say you're looking for escape key presses. In the table, you can see the vk code is 0x1B, but it has an alias `VK_ESCAPE`:

```
case WM_KEYDOWN:
    if (wParam == VK_ESCAPE) {
        //handle
    }

    break;
```

Take your pick, depending on what kinds of keys you need to handle.

Comment: so if I wanted to use WM_CHAR I would do: 
`case WM_CHAR:
     if (wParam == 'w') {
           //handle
     }
     break;'

Comment: @isANoob, That should work. However, you must call [`TranslateMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644955(v=vs.85).aspx) in your message loop before dispatching it. You should get in the habit of always doing that anyway. It is generally easier to use `WM_CHAR` over `WM_KEYDOWN` as well if chars are what you need. Also, it happens that the virtual key codes for letter keys are their uppercase ASCII equivalents ('a' and 'A' (same key) are both 65 (0x41)).

Comment: I'll be sure to keep that in mind, however the visual C++ Win32 project automatically creates that. If I am working without it, I will try to get in that habit.